# C# net finding the shortest and longest line

Tags: c#

Trying to find the longest and shortest line in a text file. Longest returns correct but the shortest is always blank, any ideas?

```
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt");            
        var Minimum = "";
        var Maximum = "";


            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                if (Maximum.Length < line.Length)
                {
                    Maximum = line;
                }


                if (Minimum.Length > line.Length)
                {
                    Minimum = line;
                }
           }
```

Comment: Maybe because you have a blank line in your file? Check the file I think it will be the last line

Comment: No blank lines, shortest line has 1 character

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are setting `var Minimum = "";` and as it's length will be 0, it will never be longer than any line in the file. Set the first line as the Minimum before the loop:

```
var Minimum = lines[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

without using loop..

```
Maximum = lines.OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).First().ToString();
Minimum = lines.OrderBy(a => a.Length).First().ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you sort twice, isn't the longest the first and shortest the last after the first sort? Also, sorting has a larger time complexity than one loop, so this solution has worse performance. It is easier to read though.

Comment: @juunas Do you have any reference that this type sorting for twice using lamda expression is slower than the for loop..

Comment: Any comparison sort has a time complexity of n log n. OPs loop is linear, thus it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum.Length is initially 0. I.e.

```
Minimum.Length > line.Length
```

will never get true, because of `line.Length >= 0` for all lines.

Solution: You should initialize `Mimimum` with the first line before iterating.