# How linq function OrderByDescending and OrderBy for string length works internally? Is it faster than doing it with loop?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, for-loop

My question is raised based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31042645/1660178), I had posted an answer on that question..[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31042828/1660178)

This is the code.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt");
var Minimum = lines[0];//Default length set
var Maximum = "";

foreach (string line in lines)
{    
    if (Maximum.Length < line.Length)
    {
        Maximum = line;
    }

    if (Minimum.Length > line.Length)
    {
        Minimum = line;
    }
}
```

and alternative for this code using LINQ (My approach)

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt");
var Maximum = lines.OrderByDescending(a => a.Length).First().ToString();
var Minimum = lines.OrderBy(a => a.Length).First().ToString();
```

LINQ is easy to read and implement..

I want to know **which one is good for performance**.
And **how Linq work internally for OrderByDescending and OrderBy for ordering by length**?

Comment: "which one is good for performance?" 1. Don't micro-optimise. Unless your app is running too slowly, you should not be worrying about performance issues like this. 2. If you really really are worried, test it for yourself.

Comment: I want to know how linq work actually  for OrderBy functionality. You an see the comments on my answer..http://stackoverflow.com/a/31042828/1660178 that is why i m asking...also for that

Comment: You should think about it... If you have done a little CS, you'll know that the first algorithm is `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in space, with `n` being the length of the collection. There are no generic orderings faster than `O(nlogn)`. And you are doing it twice!

Comment: @DavidArno I always though that that line of thought is the one that produced Windows 7... And leads to laziness

Comment: Your approach is the most efficient way. It needs only one enumeration for both.

Comment: @xanatos, Vista, I think. With WIn 7, they attached the profiler and optimised the bad spots :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter *His* approach is the LINQ one...

Comment: Small observation: `lines` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, so the `ToString()` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidArno Yep... I meant Vista :-)

Comment: @ycsun: yes, but `String.ToString` returns `this`, so it doesn't matter in terms of perforamance.

Comment: for a O(n) solution with LINQ look at [aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value/914155#914155)

Comment: Why sort at all? `lines.Max(l => l.Length)`

Comment: @knittl Because `lines.Max(l => l.Length)` won't return the longest string, but an integer representing the length of the longest string.

Comment: @sangramparmar  are you sure ??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can [read the source code for OrderBy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e449fbc07f49dc52).

Stop doing [micro-optimizing](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) or [premature-optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) on your code. Try to write code that performs correctly, then if you face a performance problem later then profile your application and see where is the problem. If you have a piece of code which have performance problem due to finding the shortest and longest string then start to optimize this part.

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:
>   premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass
>   up our opportunities in that critical 3% - Donald Knuth

`File.ReadLines` is returning an `IEnumerable<string>`, It means that if you do a foreach over it it will return data to you one by one. I think the best performance improvement you can do here is to improve the reading of file from the disk. If it is small enough to load the whole file into memory use `File.ReadAllLines`, if it is not try reading the file in big chunks that fits in memory. Reading a file line by line will cause performance degradation due to I/O operation from disk. So the problem here is not how LINQ or loop perform, The problem is in number of disk reads.

Comment: `ReadLines` might use "big chunks" internally. It does not necessarily make an I/O operation for each `.MoveNext()` or `.Current` invocation on the enumerator.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: `File.ReadLines` is just using a `StreamReader` and it's `ReadLine` method internally. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs,e7d359a7224464af,references

Comment: `ReadLine` uses [ReadBuffer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,ef2abdf7bd65b2ec) internally which may read chunk of data from disk. @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, you need to understand some points for deciding what is the best way.

First, let's think that we want to solve the problem with LINQ. Then, to write the most optimized code, you must understand **Deferred Execution**. Most Linq methods, such as `Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy`, `Skip`, `Take` and some others uses DE. So, what is Deferred Execution? It means that, these methods will not be executed unless the user doesn't need them. These methods will just create iterator. And this iterator is ready to be executed, when we need them. So, how can user make them execute? The answer is, with the help of `foreach` which will call `GetEnumerator` or other Linq methods. Such as, `ToList()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Max()` and some others.

These process will help us to gain some performance.

Now, let's come back to your problem. [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) will return `IEnumerable<string>`, which it means that, it will not read the lines, unless we need them. In your example, you have twice called sorting method for this object, which it means that it will sort this collection over again twice. Instead of that, you can sort the collection once, then call `ToList()` which will execute the `OrderedEnumerable` iterator and then get first and last element of the collection which physically inside our hands.

```
var orderedList = lines
   .OrderBy(a => a.Length) // This method uses deferred execution, so it is not executed yet
   .ToList(); // But, `ToList()` makes it to execute.

var Maximum = orderedList.Last();
var Minimum = orderedList.First();
```

BTW, you can find `OrderBy` source code, [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e449fbc07f49dc52).

It returns [`OrderedEnumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ffb8de6aefac77cc,references) instance and the sorting algorithm is here:

```
public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() 
{
    Buffer<TElement> buffer = new Buffer<TElement>(source);
    if (buffer.count > 0) 
    {
        EnumerableSorter<TElement> sorter = GetEnumerableSorter(null);
        int[] map = sorter.Sort(buffer.items, buffer.count);
        sorter = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.count; i++) yield return buffer.items[map[i]];
    }
}
```

And now, let's come back to another aspect which effects the performance. If you see, Linq uses another element to store sorted collection. Of course, it will take some memory, which tells us it is not the most efficent way.

I just tried to explain you how does Linq work. But, I am very agree with @Dotctor as a result to your overall answer. Just, don't forget that, you can use `File.ReadAllLines` which will not return `IEnumerable<stirng>`, but `string[]`. 
What does it mean? As I tried to explain in the beginning, difference is that, if it is `IEnumerable`, then .net will read line one by one when enuemrator enumerates over iterator. But, if it is `string[]`, then all lines in our application memory.

Comment: Also, `O(n log n)` isn't any better than `O(2 n log n)` in the long run.

Comment: @Rawling, your comment makes no sense to me (though the upvotes suggest others get it). Sorting twice will (on average) take half as long as doing it once, so how can you claim that they are no different?

Comment: @DavidArno Yes, sorting twice takes twice as long as sorting once, but it's pointless to make *that* optimization when you don't need to sort at all. There's no such thing as `O(2 n log n)` so there's no point switching from `O(n log n)` to `O(n log n)` when it's possible to switch to `O(n)`.

Comment: It will be actually 2O(n log n), not O(2 n log n). But anyway sorting here is pointless.

Comment: 2O(n log n) = O(2 n log n) = O(n log n) @Yura

Comment: He isn't only sorting the file twice... He is **reading** and sorting the file twice. `ReadLines` returns a `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: In terms of complexity - yes, you are right - it is O(n log n). But in terms of time it is definitely twice as long, which is more specific for performance.  @doctor.

Answer (score 8):

With the second method, you are not only sorting the lines twice... You are **reading** the file twice. This because `File.ReadLines` returns a `IEnumerable<string>`. This clearly shows why **you shouldn't ever ever** enumerate a `IEnumerable<>` twice unless you know how it was built. If you really want to do it, add a `.ToList()` or a `.ToArray()` that will materialize the `IEnumerable<>` to a collection... And while the first method has a memory footprint of a single line of text (because it reads the file one line at a time), the second method will load the whole file in memory to sort it, so will have a much bigger memory footprint, and if the file is some hundred mb, the difference is big (note that technically you could have a file with a single line of text long 1gb, so this rule isn't absolute... It is for reasonable files that have lines long up to some hundred characters :-) )

Now... Someone will tell you that premature optimization is **evil**, but I'll tell you that ignorance is **twice evil**.

If you know the difference between the two blocks of code then you can do an informed choice between the two... Otherwise you are simply randomly throwing rocks until it seems to work. Where **seems to work** is the keyword here.

Comment: "you shouldn't ever ever enumerate a IEnumerable<> twice" strongly disagree. There are many cases where eagerly evaluating the whole contents of an enumerable is stupid and wastes ridiculous amounts of memory.

Comment: @ahruss The complete sentence should be "you shouldn't ever enumerate a `IEnumerable<>` twice **unless you know how it was built**" (for example if a `is T[] == true`, then it is an array, so it is ok to enumerate it multiple times). There is no guarantee in the `IEnumerable<>` contract that the data can be read twice, or that the same data will be read if enumerated twice. Clearly even doing a `ToList()`/`ToArray()` introduces an unknown... What if the `IEnumerable<>` is bigger than memory? But from experience this case is rarer than the one "the `IEnumerable<>` is very slow to generate/read"

Comment: Very much appreciated your "premature optimization" vs. "ignorance" comment.  I feel that the whole "don't optimize prematurely" bit is too often being thrown around as an excuse to not understand how things work.  As we are getting these built-in functions that accomplish more and more with a more succinct syntax, it becomes very easy to fall into the trap of thinking that less lines of code == better performance.  Entity Framework is a perfect example where falling into this trap can be fatal.

Answer (score 7):

The most efficient approach is to avoid LINQ here, the approach using `foreach` needs only one enumeration.

If you want to put the whole file into a collection anyway you could use this:

```
List<string> orderedLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt")
    .OrderBy(l => l.Length)
    .ToList();
string shortest = orderedLines.First();
string longest  = orderedLines.Last();
```

Apart from that you should read about [LINQ's deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq).

Also note that your LINQ approach does not only order all lines twice to get the longest and the shortest, it also needs to read the whole file twice since `File.ReadLines` is using a `StreamReader`(as opposed to `ReadAllLines` which reads all lines into an array first).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you use `ReadLines`, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use
>   `ReadAllLines`, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned
>   before you can access the array

In general that can help to make your LINQ queries more efficient, f.e. if you filter out lines with `Where`, but in this case it's making things worse.

As Jeppe Stig Nielsen has mentioned in a comment, since `OrderBy` needs to create another buffer-collection internally(with `ToList` the second), there is another approach that might be more efficient:

```
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt"); 
Array.Sort(allLines, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
string shortest = allLines.First();
string longest  = allLines.Last();
```

The only drawback of [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) is that it performs an unstable sort as opposed to `OrderBy`. So if two lines have the same length the order might not be maintained.

Comment: my approach is LINQ..that is why i m asking

Comment: @sangramparmar: so the best in terms of performance is the loop.

Comment: If he wants it in a collection, he could first do `string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt"); /* note 'All' */`. That is a collection. Then `Array.Sort(allLines, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));` does a quicker sort.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: isn't that micro-optimization? Is `OrderBy` really slower than `Array.Sort`? One advantage of `OrderBy` is that it maintains the order if two lines have the same length whereas `Array.Sort` is unstable.

Comment: I think `OrderBy` must be slower. Maybe it copies everything to a new collection and then does an in-place sort there? More likely it gradually inserts the new items that are yielded by the source, into a new (private) sorted list of some type. But slower does not mean "slow". So it might very well be irrelevant in practice. Your comment about `Sort` being unstable is relevant! We do not know if the order of lines with equal lengths matters.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: thanks for the comment, i've put it into my answer :)

Comment: @sangramparmar: note that i've edited my answer considerably.